# How to copy data from one text file to another text file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

How to copy data from one text file to another text file in Matlab.in this fine numbers, characters and special symbols are included.

for example from text file -----> b.text

copy the data into -------> c.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the above answer was not accepted though it works perfectly, I would like to write other alternate solution

First Import data to matlab variable, while importing You can import in any data type comfortable for your requirement(like to struct where text and numeric data is listed separately, or to cell)

```
ImportedData = importdata('b.txt', '\n');
```

then copy the data

```
fid = fopen(c.text, 'w+');

fprintf(fid ,formatSpec,A1,...,An)
```

this should work perfectly

for further understanding look the below link

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#btf98f7

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you needn't do any change:

```
copyfile('b.txt', 'c.txt');
```

Or you can scan the file line by line, and then save your data into a new file.

```
fidin=fopen('b.txt');
while ~feof(fidin) 
tline=fgetl(fidin)  
end
fclose(fidin);
```

Check [here](https://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/text-files.html) for more useful commands.